# Inverse image of $[-2,2]$ under cosine.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I solved the following problem:

> Let $g(z) = \cos z$.  Find $g^{-1}[-2,2]$.

but my solution was kind of long.  I was wondering if there was a faster way to do this problem.

Here's my solution: Write $\cos z = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2}$, and $z = a+bi$, so $$\cos z = \frac{e^{-b + ia} + e^{b - ia}}{2} = \frac{e^{-b}}{2}[\cos a + i \sin a] + \frac{e^b}{2}[\cos a - i \sin a]$$ $$ = \frac{e^{-b} + e^b}{2} \cos a + i \frac{e^{-b} - e^b}{2} \sin a$$ We first of all want $\cos z$ to be real, so either (i) $e^{-b} - e^b = 0$ or (ii) $\sin a = 0$.  The first case is not interesting, this just says that $b = 0$, and we already know in this case that $\cos a \in [-1,1]$.  For the second case, we will have $a = k \pi$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.  This implies that $$\cos z = \pm \frac{e^{-b} + e^{b}}{2}$$ so to make $\cos z \in [-2,2]$ we need $h(b) := e^{-b} + e^b$ to be in $[-4,4]$.  Clearly $h$ is an even function, increasing in either direction, so we need to solve $e^{-x} + e^x = 4$ for $x$.  Let $y = e^x$, then $\frac{1}{y} + y =4$, so $y^2 - 4y + 1 =0$.  Then $$y= \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{16 - 4}}{2} = 2 \pm \sqrt{3}$$ so $x = \log (2 \pm \sqrt{3})$.  Looking at the equation we were supposed to solve, we know without calculating anything that $- \log(2 + \sqrt{3}) = \log(2 - \sqrt{3})$.  Letting $\alpha = \log(2 + \sqrt{3})$, it holds that $e^b + e^{-b} \leq 4$ for $- \alpha \leq b \leq \alpha$.

Thus $g^{-1}[-2,2]$ consists of the real line unioned together with $$\bigcup\limits_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \{ k \pi + bi : -\alpha \leq b \leq \alpha\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you went about this was probably the best way to handle it.  The one thing I would change is your derivation for $\cos(a+bi)$. In particular, it's quicker to use the sum of angles formula:
$$
\cos(a+bi) = \cos(a) \cos(bi) - \sin(a) \sin(bi)
$$
and take it from there.